# simulate robotic arm of my size

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, librviz, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

So I would like be able to simulate a robotic arm BUT:

- I don't have an physical arm. I just want to be able to simulate it.
- I want the robotic arm to be of whatever size I chose (in how many places it can rotate, how long each part is and so on).

In other words. I want to be able to visualize a robotic arm (in rviz maybe, not sure) with out having a robotic arm in real life. Then to be make it have whatever sizes I want.

***Can I do this with ROS and with what packages?***

Besides the simulation part, is there a package that allows me to easily move it (do the kinematics and everything)? For example, I want to be able to say to the arm "make a line from [x,y,z] to [x' , y', z'] " and then for it to see a simulated arm do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211792/simulate-robotic-arm-of-my-size/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the robot arm part, you can make an autocad/google sketchup/ drawing which can be exported as an stl or dae file. Use the stl file in a urdf file - and gazebo will be able to visualize it for you.

[This urdf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) has a section on how to use meshes (which is what you want) at the end. You could also make a custom geometry based arm using bars, and so on - but it'd be a bit more complicated.

You don't need a physical arm to do any of this.

To do the inverse kinematics part, MoveIt is the most popular that I've seen - but I've never used it - so, I can't coment about it much. have a look at it here : http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics

---

Originally posted by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) with karma: 98 on 2015-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-06-21**:
@AbdealiJK Thx for the info. I will look in to it. I will accept your answer after I have checked it :) .